# Need to make columns showing which IDs are assigned to those columns...not sure how to describe

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Each patient is assigned to two doctors. There's three doctors total. My data looks like this:

```
>df
Dr1    Dr2    PatientID
Chris  John   5
John   Mike   24
Mike   John   28
```

What I want is 3 columns (one per Dr) showing who their patients are

```
Chris   John   Mike
5       5      24
        24     28
        28
```

I am trying to play with `melt()` but not having any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option similar to Gregor's solution

```
unstack(reshape(dat, idvar = "PatientID", varying = 1:2, direction = "long", sep = ""),
        PatientID ~ Dr)
# $Chris
# [1] 5
# 
# $John
# [1] 24  5 28
# 
# $Mike
# [1] 28 24
```

**data**

```
text <- "Dr1    Dr2    PatientID
Chris  John   5
John   Mike   24
Mike   John   28"

dat <- read.table(text = text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a data frame with ragged columns (i.e., columns of different lengths) is a little tricky, but here's an attempt. Note the use of magrittr's `%$%` operator:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = 'Dr1    Dr2    PatientID
Chris  John   5
                 John   Mike   24
                 Mike   John   28', header = T)

list.per.dr <- df %>% 
  gather(doc, name, -PatientID) %>% 
  select(-doc) %$% 
  split(PatientID, name) 

$Chris
[1] 5

$John
[1] 24  5 28

$Mike
[1] 28 24
```

We now have a list object giving the patients assigned to each doctor. To convert this to a data frame, we need to equalize their lengths:

```
max_patients <- max(lengths(list.per.dr))

df.new <- list.per.dr %>% 
  lapply(function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max_patients - length(x)))) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

  Chris John Mike
1     5   24   28
2    NA    5   24
3    NA   28   NA
```

Comment: Wow! That's really cool! The only thing I notice is sometimes there will be many rows of only NAs before showing the patient assignments again. Normally I would use `df.new <- Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x)), df.new)` to remove rows of a dataframe that are ONLY NA's but it doesn't work here, any idea why?

Comment: Hard to say without example data that produces the issue. Again, a list object is probably better for these data rather than a data frame with a lot of NA values, but you requested a data frame specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Data frames are rectangular. What you want isn't rectangular, so let's make a `list` instead:

```
with(reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "PatientID"), split(PatientID, value))
# $Chris
# [1] 5
# 
# $John
# [1] 24  5 28
# 
# $Mike
# [1] 28 24
```

---

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = "Dr1    Dr2    PatientID
Chris  John   5
John   Mike   24
Mike   John   28", header = T)
```